# Stack trace doesn't reveal cause of Pure Virtual Call

Tags: c++, mfc, atl, visual-c++-6, pure-virtual

I have a legacy system written in C++ and built using Visual C++ 6.  It is an MFC 4.2 application that is multi-threaded and makes use of ATL COM objects to implement a plugin architecture.

2 or 3 times a year the release build will display the 'R6025 – pure virtual function call' popup.  This has never been reproduced in a development or test environment.  When this appears on the server application clients maintain their connections but any data is not updated with the exception of the time.  The time is the only data point not sourced from the plugin system.  This would suggest the equipment manager object (see below) is being blocked by the popup.  Since this has not been reproducible off-site I have updated the installation to include the PDBs and given the on-site engineer instructions on how to produce a stack trace of all running threads at the point when the dialog pops up.

I was hoping that the stack trace would show where the pure call originates however the thread that shows the pure call pop up starts with the pure call itself.

I have read various causes of this outside of the most common (calling virtual function from a constructor/destructor) and the most likely cause would seem to be accessing a COM object that has been released.  The equipment manager hosts a thread for each 'resource' (COM ports basically) and each thread will continuously query the handful of plugin objects that share it for their poll ratio which requires a query interface / release to occur.  However, there should be no cross thread activity and using _ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES confirms it.  This is, of course, in the development environment and the problem isn't occuring in this instance.

What I'm looking for is any ideas on how to figure out why this pure call error is happening.  I have tried redefining the pure call function in but this only traps simulated calls in the main application, plugins still go to the pop up.  I can't set the pure call handler because it is VC6.  In any case, how would generating stack traces and dumps from my own handler wouldn't be any different than that seen in the stack trace?

This is the stack trace, edited for modesty:

```
`.  0  Id: 518.4d4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\MFC42.DLL - 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0012fecc 73dd1203 0042c0fc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0012fee8 73dda979 0042c0c8 0042c0c8 0012ffc0 MFC42!Ordinal5307+0x13
0012ff00 73ddc1f0 00320034 001423bc 00000000 MFC42!Ordinal5715+0x46
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\product.exe
0012ff10 00417327 00400000 00000000 001423bc MFC42!Ordinal1576+0x68
0012ff24 00416843 00400000 00000000 001423bc product!WinMain+0x15 [appmodul.cpp @ 30]
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 product!WinMainCRTStartup+0x134

   1  Id: 518.5bc Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll - 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
00e4e4cc 7e4249c4 001303b0 00000000 00000001 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
00e4e4f4 7e43a956 7e410000 00184450 00000000 USER32!GetCursorFrameInfo+0x1cc
00e4e7b4 7e43a2bc 00e4e910 00000000 ffffffff USER32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x677
00e4e904 7e4663fd 00e4e910 00000028 00000000 USER32!MessageBoxIndirectA+0x23a
00e4e95c 7e4664a2 00000000 025e9288 0e962870 USER32!MessageBoxTimeoutW+0x7a
00e4e990 7e450877 00000000 781c3808 78194898 USER32!MessageBoxTimeoutA+0x9c
00e4e9b0 7e45082f 00000000 781c3808 78194898 USER32!MessageBoxExA+0x1b
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4027_x-ww_e69378d0\MSVCR80.dll - 
00e4e9cc 78139882 00000000 781c3808 78194898 USER32!MessageBoxA+0x45
00e4ea10 78131c2c 781c3808 78194898 00012010 MSVCR80!rand_s+0x4fb
00e4ea34 7816a7e6 00000019 337dd9ae 043bd128 MSVCR80!c_exit+0x1bd
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 MSVCR80!purecall+0x19

   2  Id: 518.27c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffda000 Unfrozen
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll - 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0145ff3c 7c802542 0000016c 000493e0 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll - 
0145ff50 77596d1c 0000016c 000493e0 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
0145ff6c 775670c1 0000016c 00007530 7c802550 ole32!CoInstall+0x11d
0145ff8c 775263cc 0145ffb4 774fe4a2 77607a18 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xff10
0145ff94 774fe4a2 77607a18 00000000 001619b0 ole32!CoGetObject+0x1776
0145ffb4 7c80b729 001619b0 00000000 00e4e102 ole32!StringFromGUID2+0x5dc
0145ffec 00000000 774fe4ef 001619b0 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

   3  Id: 518.6d0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd7000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0188ff08 7c802542 000001c4 00001388 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSJET35.DLL - 
0188ff1c 04001a05 000001c4 00001388 04001c07 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
0188ff28 04001c07 00001388 0188ff78 016bc720 MSJET35!Ordinal153+0x507
0188ff50 0401463c 0188ff78 0188ffec 00e4f88c MSJET35!Ordinal153+0x709
0188ff60 7c911028 040fa598 016bc720 000002b3 MSJET35!Ordinal154+0x11ad
0188ffac 7c90da1a 7c91998d 7c80b729 040fa598 ntdll!wcsncpy+0xaa9
0188ffb0 7c91998d 7c80b729 040fa598 00e4f88c ntdll!ZwRegisterThreadTerminatePort+0xc
0188ffb4 7c80b729 040fa598 00e4f88c 7c911028 ntdll!CsrNewThread+0xb
0188ffc0 7c911028 040fa598 7ffd7000 8a81d600 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba
0188ffc4 040fa598 7ffd7000 8a81d600 0188ffc0 ntdll!wcsncpy+0xaa9
0188ffc8 7ffd7000 8a81d600 0188ffc0 88dd6cb0 MSJET35!Ordinal1010+0x13b0b
0188ffcc 8a81d600 0188ffc0 88dd6cb0 ffffffff 0x7ffd7000
0188ffd0 0188ffc0 88dd6cb0 ffffffff 7c839ad8 0x8a81d600
0188ffd4 88dd6cb0 ffffffff 7c839ad8 7c80b730 0x188ffc0
0188ffd8 ffffffff 7c839ad8 7c80b730 00000000 0x88dd6cb0
0188ffdc 7c839ad8 7c80b730 00000000 00000000 0xffffffff
0188ffe0 7c80b730 00000000 00000000 00000000 kernel32!ValidateLocale+0x2b0
0188ffe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 0401451f kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1c1

   4  Id: 518.6d4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd6000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0198ff08 7c802542 000001c4 ffffffff 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0198ff1c 04001a05 000001c4 ffffffff 04001c07 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
0198ff28 04001c07 ffffffff 0198ff78 016bc7f8 MSJET35!Ordinal153+0x507
0198ff50 0401463c 0198ff78 0198ffec 00e4f88c MSJET35!Ordinal153+0x709
0198ff60 7c911028 040fa598 016bc720 000002b3 MSJET35!Ordinal154+0x11ad
0198ffac 7c90da1a 7c91998d 7c80b729 040fa598 ntdll!wcsncpy+0xaa9
0198ffb0 7c91998d 7c80b729 040fa598 00e4f88c ntdll!ZwRegisterThreadTerminatePort+0xc
0198ffb4 7c80b729 040fa598 00e4f88c 7c911028 ntdll!CsrNewThread+0xb
0198ffc0 7c911028 040fa598 7ffd6000 8a81f600 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba
0198ffc4 040fa598 7ffd6000 8a81f600 0198ffc0 ntdll!wcsncpy+0xaa9
0198ffc8 7ffd6000 8a81f600 0198ffc0 88dd6c78 MSJET35!Ordinal1010+0x13b0b
0198ffcc 8a81f600 0198ffc0 88dd6c78 ffffffff 0x7ffd6000
0198ffd0 0198ffc0 88dd6c78 ffffffff 7c839ad8 0x8a81f600
0198ffd4 88dd6c78 ffffffff 7c839ad8 7c80b730 0x198ffc0
0198ffd8 ffffffff 7c839ad8 7c80b730 00000000 0x88dd6c78
0198ffdc 7c839ad8 7c80b730 00000000 00000000 0xffffffff
0198ffe0 7c80b730 00000000 00000000 00000000 kernel32!ValidateLocale+0x2b0
0198ffe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 0401451f kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1c1

   5  Id: 518.6d8 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd5000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
01a8ff08 7c802542 000001c4 ffffffff 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01a8ff1c 04001a05 000001c4 ffffffff 04001c07 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
01a8ff28 04001c07 ffffffff 01a8ff78 016bc7f8 MSJET35!Ordinal153+0x507
01a8ff50 0401463c 01a8ff78 01a8ffec 00e4f88c MSJET35!Ordinal153+0x709
01a8ff60 7c911028 040fa598 016bc720 000002b3 MSJET35!Ordinal154+0x11ad
01a8ffac 7c90da1a 7c91998d 7c80b729 040fa598 ntdll!wcsncpy+0xaa9
01a8ffb0 7c91998d 7c80b729 040fa598 00e4f88c ntdll!ZwRegisterThreadTerminatePort+0xc
01a8ffb4 7c80b729 040fa598 00e4f88c 7c911028 ntdll!CsrNewThread+0xb
01a8ffc0 7c911028 040fa598 7ffd5000 8a81d600 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba
01a8ffc4 040fa598 7ffd5000 8a81d600 01a8ffc0 ntdll!wcsncpy+0xaa9
01a8ffc8 7ffd5000 8a81d600 01a8ffc0 88dd6c40 MSJET35!Ordinal1010+0x13b0b
01a8ffcc 8a81d600 01a8ffc0 88dd6c40 ffffffff 0x7ffd5000
01a8ffd0 01a8ffc0 88dd6c40 ffffffff 7c839ad8 0x8a81d600
01a8ffd4 88dd6c40 ffffffff 7c839ad8 7c80b730 0x1a8ffc0
01a8ffd8 ffffffff 7c839ad8 7c80b730 00000000 0x88dd6c40
01a8ffdc 7c839ad8 7c80b730 00000000 00000000 0xffffffff
01a8ffe0 7c80b730 00000000 00000000 00000000 kernel32!ValidateLocale+0x2b0
01a8ffe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 0401451f kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1c1

   6  Id: 518.6f0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd4000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
01bcffb4 7c80b729 71a67b03 00e4f9d4 7c90e920 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01bcffec 00000000 71a5d2c6 0017ef48 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

   7  Id: 518.6f4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffaf000 Unfrozen
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\msscript.ocx - 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
01ccff3c 585a881f 01ccff60 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll - 
01ccff80 77c3a3b0 00000000 585b2070 7c80e0e8 msscript!DLLGetDocumentation+0x2c1f
01ccffb4 7c80b729 00c2d3c0 585b2070 7c80e0e8 msvcrt!endthreadex+0xa9
01ccffec 00000000 77c3a341 00c2d3c0 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

   8  Id: 518.6c0 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffae000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
023afe74 7c812f0c 00000000 00000001 00000001 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
023afe98 73deaa49 00000000 00000001 00000001 kernel32!CreateSemaphoreA+0x4f
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Program Files\company name\product\ErrorLanguage.dll
023afec4 10002fde 00000001 00000001 1000c0b0 MFC42!Ordinal518+0x35
023aff10 73ddfb30 00000000 ffffffff 01cd29d8 ErrorLanguage!SoundQueueProc+0x6e
023aff80 77c3a3b0 0012faf8 ffffffff 7e471088 MFC42!Ordinal2256+0x1ca
023affb4 7c80b729 00c2d3c0 ffffffff 7e471088 msvcrt!endthreadex+0xa9
023affec 00000000 77c3a341 00c2d3c0 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

   9  Id: 518.a68 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffd8000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03e7f5e4 7e4195f9 00000002 03e7f60c 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
03e7f640 7752e73e 00000001 03e7f688 000003e8 USER32!GetLastInputInfo+0x105
03e7f668 7752e865 03e7f688 000003e8 03e7f698 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x13e2
03e7f690 77525b11 ffffffff 03e7f788 03e7f6c0 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x1509
03e7f6a0 77602efe 0015f3c8 03e7f788 00000000 ole32!CoGetObject+0xebb
03e7f6c0 7760208a 03e7f788 0018cf38 03e7f7e4 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x11cee
03e7f7a0 7752e912 0018cf38 03e7f8b4 03e7f8a4 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x10e7a
03e7f7bc 7752e8bb 03e7f8b4 03e7f8a4 0018cf38 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x15b6
03e7f828 7752c91a 0018cf38 03e7f8b4 03e7f8a4 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x155f
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll - 
03e7f87c 77ef5db5 0018cf38 03e7f8b4 03e7f8a4 ole32!ReleaseStgMedium+0x127f
03e7f898 77ef5ead 0014adac 03e7f8e0 0300002c RPCRT4!NdrProxySendReceive+0x40
03e7fc7c 77ef5e42 0016d430 0016d796 03e7fcb4 RPCRT4!NdrProxySendReceive+0x138
03e7fc9c 77e88519 0000000c 00000016 03e7fcec RPCRT4!NdrProxySendReceive+0xcd
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for c:\Program Files\company name\product\pluginThreeObject.dll
03e7fcac 02dc18fe 0014adac 00000000 02e121ac RPCRT4!CreateStubFromTypeInfo+0x11c
03e7fcec 02dbe47c 03e7fcb8 00000001 02e12100 pluginThreeObject!CX25::Send+0x392
03e7fd20 02dbe2e8 02e19c58 00000001 00000000 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::TransmitMessage+0x3d
03e7fd50 02dbe136 02e12100 00000003 02e19c58 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::SendWaitReply+0x1f
03e7fd88 02dbdf90 02e12100 02e19c58 02e19c58 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::SendMessageA+0x4d
03e7fda4 02dbdec8 02e12100 02e19c58 00000000 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::SendScanMessage+0x14
03e7fdd8 02db48b7 02e12100 02e121a0 00000004 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::ScanOutstation+0xfc
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for c:\Program Files\company name\product\EquipmentManagerObject.dll
03e7fe58 00e62db0 02df11e0 0014adac 5bdd1fca pluginThreeObject!CpluginThree::raw_Poll+0x2e8
03e7ff90 00e629a6 02c86f30 00000000 03e7ffac EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::RunResourceThread+0xd6 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 360]
03e7ffa0 00e64f5e 02c86f30 03e7ffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
03e7ffac 00e64f25 03e7ffec 7c80b729 02c86f30 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
03e7ffb4 7c80b729 02c86f30 00000000 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
03e7ffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c86f30 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  10  Id: 518.a9c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffac000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
089ffdac 7c802455 000001f4 00000000 089ffddc ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for c:\Program Files\company name\product\pluginOneObject.dll
089ffdbc 02d929e8 000001f4 01d0a190 5bdd1fd9 kernel32!Sleep+0xf
089ffddc 02d91ce1 089ffe48 089ffe3c 00000000 pluginOneObject!CpluginOne::GetChar+0x6b
089ffe58 00e62db0 5bdce91a 0c959288 089fff70 pluginOneObject!CpluginOne::raw_Poll+0xf3
089fff90 00e629a6 02c87a30 00000000 089fffac EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::RunResourceThread+0xd6 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 360]
089fffa0 00e64f5e 02c87a30 089fffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
089fffac 00e64f25 089fffec 7c80b729 02c87a30 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
089fffb4 7c80b729 02c87a30 00000000 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
089fffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c87a30 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  11  Id: 518.b40 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffab000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
08aff5e4 7e4195f9 00000002 08aff60c 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
08aff640 7752e73e 00000001 08aff688 000003e8 USER32!GetLastInputInfo+0x105
08aff668 7752e865 08aff688 000003e8 08aff698 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x13e2
08aff690 77525b11 ffffffff 08aff788 08aff6c0 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x1509
08aff6a0 77602efe 0015f3c8 08aff788 00000000 ole32!CoGetObject+0xebb
08aff6c0 7760208a 08aff788 001dfcc8 08aff7e4 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x11cee
08aff7a0 7752e912 001dfcc8 08aff8b4 08aff8a4 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x10e7a
08aff7bc 7752e8bb 08aff8b4 08aff8a4 001dfcc8 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x15b6
08aff828 7752c91a 001dfcc8 08aff8b4 08aff8a4 ole32!CoUnmarshalInterface+0x155f
08aff87c 77ef5db5 001dfcc8 08aff8b4 08aff8a4 ole32!ReleaseStgMedium+0x127f
08aff898 77ef5ead 001e319c 08aff8e0 0300002c RPCRT4!NdrProxySendReceive+0x40
08affc7c 77ef5e42 0016d430 0016d796 08affcb4 RPCRT4!NdrProxySendReceive+0x138
08affc9c 77e88519 0000000c 00000016 08affcec RPCRT4!NdrProxySendReceive+0xcd
08affcac 02dc18fe 001e319c 00000000 02e1b864 RPCRT4!CreateStubFromTypeInfo+0x11c
08affcec 02dbe47c 08affcb8 00000001 02e1b7b8 pluginThreeObject!CX25::Send+0x392
08affd20 02dbe2e8 02e27aa0 00000001 00000000 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::TransmitMessage+0x3d
08affd50 02dbe136 02e1b7b8 00000003 02e27aa0 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::SendWaitReply+0x1f
08affd88 02dbdf90 02e1b7b8 02e27aa0 02e27aa0 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::SendMessageA+0x4d
08affda4 02dbdec8 02e1b7b8 02e27aa0 00000000 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::SendScanMessage+0x14
08affdd8 02db48b7 02e1b7b8 02e1b858 00000003 pluginThreeObject!COutstation::ScanOutstation+0xfc
08affe58 00e62db0 02df11e0 001e319c 5bdd1fca pluginThreeObject!CpluginThree::raw_Poll+0x2e8
08afff90 00e629a6 02c88518 00000000 08afffac EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::RunResourceThread+0xd6 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 360]
08afffa0 00e64f5e 02c88518 08afffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
08afffac 00e64f25 08afffec 7c80b729 02c88518 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
08afffb4 7c80b729 02c88518 00000000 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
08afffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c88518 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  12  Id: 518.b48 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa9000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
08cffdbc 7c802455 000003e8 00000000 08cffe58 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for c:\Program Files\company name\product\pluginTwoObject.dll
08cffdcc 02f31a65 000003e8 00000000 00e4fcc4 kernel32!Sleep+0xf
08cffe58 00e62db0 5bdd1b84 73e9c710 08cfff70 pluginTwoObject!CpluginOne::raw_Poll+0xa0
08cfff90 00e629a6 02c890e8 00000000 08cfffac EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::RunResourceThread+0xd6 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 360]
08cfffa0 00e64f5e 02c890e8 08cfffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
08cfffac 00e64f25 08cfffec 7c80b729 02c890e8 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
08cfffb4 7c80b729 02c890e8 00000000 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
08cfffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c890e8 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  13  Id: 518.b50 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa7000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
08efff90 00e629a6 02c89bb8 00000000 08efffac pluginThreeObject!_EH_prolog+0x2
08efffa0 00e64f5e 02c89bb8 08efffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
08efffac 00e64f25 08efffec 7c80b729 02c89bb8 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
08efffb4 7c80b729 02c89bb8 00000000 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
08efffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c89bb8 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  14  Id: 518.b54 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa6000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
08fffb50 7c802455 000001f4 00000000 08fffb88 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for c:\Program Files\company name\product\TimeSyncObject.dll
08fffb60 02f62a2f 000001f4 00000000 00000000 kernel32!Sleep+0xf
08fffb88 02f63d52 08fffd0c 08fffd24 01d04580 TimeSyncObject!CTimeSync::GetValue+0x141 [C:\src\product\timesyncobject\TimeSync.cpp @ 816]
08fffd38 02f61991 08fffd98 77dd7b68 00000002 TimeSyncObject!CTimeSync::GetTimeInterrogator210Message+0x46 [C:\src\product\timesyncobject\TimeSync.cpp @ 1491]
08fffe58 00e62db0 01d04590 001e70a4 08ffff70 TimeSyncObject!CTimeSync::raw_Poll+0x198 [C:\src\product\timesyncobject\TimeSync.cpp @ 320]
08ffff90 00e629a6 02c8a688 00000000 08ffffac EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::RunResourceThread+0xd6 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 360]
08ffffa0 00e64f5e 02c8a688 08ffffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
08ffffac 00e64f25 08ffffec 7c80b729 02c8a688 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
08ffffb4 7c80b729 02c8a688 00000000 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
08ffffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c8a688 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  15  Id: 518.b60 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa5000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
090ffe50 7c802455 00000001 00000000 090fff90 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
090ffe60 00e63145 00000001 00140178 00e4fcc4 kernel32!Sleep+0xf
090fff90 00e629a6 02c8b1d8 00000000 090fffac EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::RunResourceThread+0x46b [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 419]
090fffa0 00e64f5e 02c8b1d8 090fffb4 00e64f25 EquipmentManagerObject!CResourceThread::ThreadProc+0x37 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\ResourceThread.cpp @ 189]
090fffac 00e64f25 090fffec 7c80b729 02c8b1d8 EquipmentManagerObject!CThread::ThreadFirst+0x11 [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 151]
090fffb4 7c80b729 02c8b1d8 00140178 00e4fcc4 EquipmentManagerObject!Thread+0xb [C:\src\product\equipmentmanagerobject\Thread.cpp @ 66]
090fffec 00000000 00e64f1a 02c8b1d8 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  16  Id: 518.b64 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa4000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
092ffd70 7c802542 00000500 00002710 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\comsvcs.dll - 
092ffd84 76663ba1 00000500 00002710 7c9121b4 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
092fffb4 7c80b729 001e5b5c 7c9121b4 7c912221 comsvcs!DispManGetContext+0x29c
092fffec 00000000 76663aaf 001e5b5c 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  17  Id: 518.b68 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa3000 Unfrozen
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for c:\WINDOWS\system32\sqlncli10.dll - 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
093fff6c 3381b493 00000574 093fff9c 093fff98 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
093fffb4 7c80b729 00000000 7c93530a 00000210 sqlncli10!DllMain+0x3d13
093fffec 00000000 3381b422 00000000 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  18  Id: 518.b34 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffaa000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0988ff80 77e76caf 0988ffa8 77e76ad1 00143350 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0988ff88 77e76ad1 00143350 00110010 7c80903c RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree+0x61c
0988ffa8 77e76c97 001590f0 0988ffec 7c80b729 RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree+0x43e
0988ffb4 7c80b729 0e869e90 00110010 7c80903c RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree+0x604
0988ffec 00000000 77e76c7d 0e869e90 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  19  Id: 518.c4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa2000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0e5af850 77ef5ca9 00000000 77ef52df 01e54d80 RPCRT4!RpcSsDestroyClientContext+0x76a
0e5afc58 77ef6ea4 001e0150 0018844c 001e71d0 RPCRT4!NdrStubInitialize+0xa2
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll - 
0e5afcb0 771329af 001e0150 001e71d0 0018844c RPCRT4!NdrCStdStubBuffer2_Release+0x260
0e5afcd4 77601c15 00187c88 001e71d0 0018844c OLEAUT32!DllGetClassObject+0x182
0e5afd14 77601bbf 001e71d0 0016a174 00165b74 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x10a05
0e5afd5c 7752a896 001e71d0 0018b5b8 00187c88 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x109af
0e5afe34 7752a7bb 0018844c 00000000 00187c88 ole32!CoRevokeClassObject+0xa3e
0e5afe50 776017f5 001e71d0 00000001 00187c88 ole32!CoRevokeClassObject+0x963
0e5afe80 77603df3 001e7178 0018844c 00187c88 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x105e5
0e5aff54 77601dd6 001e7178 00160490 00000000 ole32!WdtpInterfacePointer_UserMarshal+0x80e
0e5aff80 7752b313 001e7178 7c802550 0e94f210 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x10bc6
0e5aff94 774fe4a2 001e7178 03e7f750 0e94f210 ole32!DcomChannelSetHResult+0x5f4
0e5affb4 7c80b729 0e94f210 03e7f750 7c810644 ole32!StringFromGUID2+0x5dc
0e5affec 00000000 774fe4ef 0e94f210 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  20  Id: 518.658 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffa1000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0e6aff8c 774fe4cd 00000480 00007530 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0e6affb4 7c80b729 0e95d5e0 7c810644 0e94f210 ole32!StringFromGUID2+0x607
0e6affec 00000000 774fe4ef 0e95d5e0 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  21  Id: 518.e10 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdc000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0125ff8c 774fe4cd 00000684 00007530 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0125ffb4 7c80b729 0e94ad30 00000020 7c810644 ole32!StringFromGUID2+0x607
0125ffec 00000000 774fe4ef 0e94ad30 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  22  Id: 518.a04 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffad000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0978ff80 77e76caf 0978ffa8 77e76ad1 00143350 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0978ff88 77e76ad1 00143350 00110010 7c80903c RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree+0x61c
0978ffa8 77e76c97 001590f0 0978ffec 7c80b729 RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree+0x43e
0978ffb4 7c80b729 0e890e30 00110010 7c80903c RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree+0x604
0978ffec 00000000 77e76c7d 0e890e30 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

  23  Id: 518.270 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdb000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
08bffcd4 77601c15 00184aa8 025e60b0 001654f0 OLEAUT32!DllGetClassObject+0x184
08bffd14 77601bbf 025e60b0 0016a174 001659d0 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x10a05
08bffd5c 7752a896 025e60b0 00186de8 00184aa8 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x109af
08bffe34 7752a7bb 001654f0 00000000 00184aa8 ole32!CoRevokeClassObject+0xa3e
08bffe50 776017f5 025e60b0 00000001 00184aa8 ole32!CoRevokeClassObject+0x963
08bffe80 77603df3 025e6058 001654f0 00184aa8 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x105e5
08bfff54 77601dd6 025e6058 0015ffe0 00000000 ole32!WdtpInterfacePointer_UserMarshal+0x80e
08bfff80 7752b313 025e6058 7c802550 0e9616b8 ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile+0x10bc6
08bfff94 774fe4a2 025e6058 08eff670 0e9616b8 ole32!DcomChannelSetHResult+0x5f4
08bfffb4 7c80b729 0e9616b8 08eff670 7c90e920 ole32!StringFromGUID2+0x5dc
08bfffec 00000000 774fe4ef 0e9616b8 00000000 kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba
quit:
`
```

Comment: I ran out of space to add this but I have also noticed that the pure call is generated form VC80 rather than the VC6 libraries it is linked with.  Other applications on the same machine use the newer libraries.  I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612702/what-can-cause-a-pure-virtual-function-call-in-c